# Psionic sorcery casting retrained Psionic spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer

If an aberrant mind sorcerer casts a spell from the *Psionic spells* feature, they may use the *Psionic sorcery* too

> When you cast any spell of 1st level or higher from your Psionic Spells feature, you can cast it by expending a spell slot as normal or by spending a number of sorcery points equal to the spell's level.
> If you cast the spell using sorcery points, it requires no verbal or somatic components, and it requires no material components, unless they are consumed by the spell

However, the *Psionic spells* feature allows you too

> You learn additional spells when you reach certain levels in this class, as shown on the Psionic Spells
> table. Each of these spells counts as a sorcerer spell for you, but it doesn't count against the number of sorcerer spells you know.
> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be a divination or an enchantment spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list.

If you "retrain" one of the spells from [calm emotions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/calm-emotions) too [Tongues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tongues) could you then cast tongues for 3 sorcery points instead of a spell slot and without using verbal or material components?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov if i retrain a spell within the Psionic spell ability, do all the benefits of Psionic sorcery apply too the retrained spell as well?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I believe they are asking whether trading out a Psionic Spells spell has the *new* spell also count as being "from your Psionic Spells feature"

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, this works.

Suppose we retrain *calm emotions* for *tongues* according to the Psionic Spells feature:

> Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level.

Therefore, we learned *tongues* through the Psionic Spells feature.

Psionic Sorcery says:

> When you cast any spell of 1st level or higher from your Psionic Spells feature...

So our recently learned *tongues* qualifies.

Comment: thank you, i wanted to clarify because the wording got confusing with how many uses of  Psionic, spell, sorcery, sorcerer